# How to Hide Payment Method in Woocommerce based on Postal Code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In this woocommerce setup, I have 2 Payment methods, **Paypal** and **Cash on Delivery**.

Now how can **Cash on Delivery** be hidden/disabled for certain Postal codes only.

This is the code I found on Gist

```
//  Disable gateway based on country
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['ccavenue'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() <> 'IN' ) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['ccavenue'] );
    } else if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() == 'IN' ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/kloon/3972435)

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I would like to do this as well as charge additional fee for COD.

Comment: This plugin does what you need: http://gremlin.io/shop/woocommerce-plugins/restrict-check-cod-payment-method-zip-pin-codes-woocommerce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable/hidden "Cash on Delivery", Place this code in your theme's function.php  .

For more detail: [woocommerce-hide-payment-gatway-based-on-visitors-country](http://codefuel.in/woocommerce-hide-payment-gatway-based-on-visitors-country/)

```
//  Disable gateway based on country
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() <> 'IN' ) {
    unset(  $available_gateways['cod'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

Comment: Nice solution. You can also add a condition to make cod the only available gateway using a determined shipping method using this gist https://gist.github.com/salgua/30ee2bc205d71f758fd9

Answer (score 0):

In the "checkout page" user can have two addresses - billing and shipping one.

To work correctly only with changes of Shipping one if it's filled I changed a bit the code. You have to test shipping countrycode if it's set, if not just user countrycode:

```
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $country = !empty($woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country()) ? $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country() : $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $country <> 'CZ' ) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you used country code to disable payment gateway by, but you mentioned you would like to do it by Postal Code.

You're right about using `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`, but instead of using `$woocommerce->customer->get_country()` you have to use `WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode()` (or `WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode()` for some situations).

You mentioned PayPal and Cash on Delivery payment gateway, we need their IDs, there are `paypal` and `cod` accordingly.

In the code below let's deactivate Cash on Delivery for a couple postal codes, for example '1234' and '5678':

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', function( $available_gateways ) {
    
    // if Cash on Delivery is already disabled, let's exit the function
    if( empty( $available_gateways['cod'] ) ) {
        return $available_gateways['cod'];
    }

    // get postal code
    $postal_code = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode();

    // deactivate payment method
    if( in_array( $postal_code, array( '1234', '5678' ) ) ) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
        
    return $available_gateways;

} );
```

Code can be inserted to your current theme functions.php file or a custom plugin. More info you can find in this tutorial: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/hide-payment-methods-based-on-postal-code.html

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.