# woocommerce payment methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to edit woocommerce payment according to chosen shipping method. I tried it like this, but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','wpml_filter_gateways',1);

function wpml_filter_gateways( $gateways ) {
if( isset( $available_methods['flat_rate:dobirka'] )){
 unset($gateways['paypal']);
 }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: What you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to hide the paypal option if I select particular shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

See [link1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/restrict-payment-options-based-on-product), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015173/how-to-hide-payment-method-in-woocommerce-based-on-postal-code)...

May be it will help you...

```
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways )
{
    global $woocommerce;
    if( YOUR-CONDITION ){
        unset($available_methods['paypal']);
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already found there discussions before. The problem is rather how to get the $available_methods. It doesn't work if they are not in the function parameters.

Comment: Please don't post only link answer. Atleast post some part of it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it like this, but still doesn't work.

`function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways )
{
    global $woocommerce;
    if( isset( $available_methods['flat_rate'] )  ){
        unset($available_methods['paypal']);
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );`

Comment: Just print `$available_methods` variable and see what's in it...
than use condition according variable values...

Comment: There is nothing. The problem is that $available_methods has to be in the function argument - like function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways, $available_methods ) so you can work with it in the function.